# Node Red + Grafana on internet with Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm using node red and Grafana on an EC2 instance(AWS).

I have a registered domain and I'm able to join my grafana (port 3000) on internet by searching localhost (without :3000) or my domain on internet. I'm using certbot for my certificates.

But now I can't access to my nodered (port 1880). I would like to have access to my node red with the same website or just with a TCP connection by taping localhost:1880 (it's not important if my node red is not connected to internet).

I have tried many different configurations. This is the last I have tried on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


  server_name domain www.domain;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}


 server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


  server_name sub.domain www.sub.domain;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1880;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to `/home/ubuntu/.node-red/settings.js` and then uncomment:

```
 httpRoot: '/nodered',
```

Step 2: You need to go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and edit this:

```
  server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            root /var/www/html;

            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name yourdomain www.yourdomain;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

             location  /nodered {
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:1880;
            }


    }
```

Finnaly you cann acces to your grafana with yourdomain
and access to node red with yourdomain/nodered